# Different results in cx_Oracle compared with SQL Developer

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I work with Oracle database and cx_oracle. The problem I have is that when I have a query, it returns the wrong answer in cx_oracle. But this query is the correct answer in SQL developer. What is my problem?
This is my query:

```
select id from my_table
```

in sql developer we have the right result, but
Returns deleted records in cx_oracle.It looks like the records is cached and returned.

Comment: I think what is happening is - You might have deleted records from my_table using SQLDeveloper and not committed it. As SQLDeveloper query is in same transaction hence it doesn't pick up the deleted rows, whereas cx_Oracle is creating a new transaction and hence picks up deleted row.

Comment: Thank you. How can I commit in oracle?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_4010.htm

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: In SQL Developer, there are Commit and Rollback icons on the toolbar at the top of each SQL Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You might not COMMITED the delete on SqlDeveloper.